# Open Bootstrap modal based on a HASH in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can i open the `delete` bootstrap modal after page load if the URL has a `HASH` with an `id` parameter?

Example:

http://example.com/properties#delete-86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do at the begining of your script :

```
// You can retrieve the id in 'matches' variable if needed
if (matches = window.location.href.match(/#delete-([0-9])+/))
{
    $('#my-modal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: console.log( window.location.href.match(new RegExp('/#delete-([0-9])+/')));
is null .

Comment: Works for me without `new RegExp`, I update my answer